# Xamarin.forms A flash of white screen after Splashscreen (Android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

This question has been asked several time on SO and xamarin.forums. But I didn't able to solve this.

In my xamarin.forms android app I have a splash screen.It launches perfectly. The problem is between loading my Mainpage and splash screen, there will be a flash of white screen occuring. I followed the tutorial from https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms/.

I tried the by creating specific activity for splashscreen and also directly setting the splash theme to MainActivity. In both ways I can't get rid of the white screen flashing.I tried it on release mode and the problem persist. Is it an expected behavior using xamarin? How can I remove that? Any help is apprecieted.

**My MainActivty**

```
   [Activity(Label = "SampleApp", Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher", Theme = "@style/splashscreen", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        static readonly string TAG = "MainActivity";
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;           
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
            base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }           
}
```

I have several libarary `Init()` inside MainActivity which I am not including here.

**My App.Xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class App : Application
    {

        public App()
        { 
                var Login = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
                MainPage = Login

        }
        protected override void OnStart()
        {            
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
```

**My Style**

```
<style name="splashscreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/Splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>  
  </style>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>


    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>

    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
```

**My drawable/Splash**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/splash_background"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/Logo"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Can you share a gif/video with the flashing? I have also followed this tutorial in the past and I haven't seen any flashing. Also, can you share the splash screen code?

Comment: @MihailDuchev Hi , I am not using splash screen activity. I simply setting the splash theme in mainactvity and replace the theme to MainTheme using base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);

Comment: @MihailDuchev Earlier I tried with Splash actvity, but it doesn't have much effect on this issue

Comment: You should add `splashscreen` style here

Comment: @Prateek I added the style

Comment: What is `@drawable/Splash`

Comment: @Prateek Sorry for not mentioning. Please find my edited code

Comment: is splash_background white color , i think thats causing it

Comment: @Prateek My splash_backgroundcolor is   <color name="splash_background">#031F24</color>

Comment: @Prateek This white color is really annoying bro

Comment: @Anand did you get a solution ?

Comment: @Venky what I done was, making the background color same for maintheme and splashtheme. So the white screen will not appear. The reason was defaultly the background color for maintheme is white. Can you try this way?

Comment: dang it, it wont work for me, i have a backgroundimage and there's one more image to be centered on it @Anand

Comment: @Venky Is your app background is white? Can you set the color same as your spalscreen background image on MainTheme background

Comment: so i should set the background image same as splash screen for main activity?

Comment: @Venky I hope you have two themes. I will tell my case. I have two themes like splashTheme and MainTheme inside my styles.xml. I set the background of splashtheme by   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/Splash</item>. I set the same for Maintheme also. In my case the background color for my splashscreen and rest of the app is  quite similar. So the white screen gone. Can you try this?

Comment: @Venky In simply set the same background   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/Splash</item> for MainTheme also

Comment: yea was thinking the same, Got it @Anand

Comment: @Anand i tried this, but then the background remains as it is on my first page

Comment: @Venky You are develping forms app right? So is you xaml background color not recognizing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding this to your style:

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
```

Like this:

```xml
<style name="splashscreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/Splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item> //Add this line
</style>
```

I recommend use SplashActivity.cs and add

```
AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoAnimation);
```

Like this:

```cs
[Activity(
    Icon = "@mipmap/icon",
    RoundIcon = "@mipmap/icon_round",
    Theme = "@style/SplashTheme",
    MainLauncher = true,
    NoHistory = true,
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = StatusBarVisibility.Visible;
            Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        }

        InvokeMainActivity();
    }

    private void InvokeMainActivity()
    {
        var mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        mainActivityIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoAnimation); //Add this line
        StartActivity(mainActivityIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me check Wilson

Comment: Hi I tried your code. Now it will stuck on splashscreen. Doesnt navigate to mainpage

Comment: You should remove `base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);` from your MainActivity and change `Theme = "@style/splashscreen"` to `Theme = "@style/MainTheme"`

Comment: Wilson. The same issue persist

Comment: I think the reason is due to the background color of Maintheme background.Which is white.  can we have any workarounds in that portion?

Comment: Thanks, this improved the transition between SplashScreen and Forms MainPage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the NavigationPage object

Replace all navigation with shell and it will be fixed.
Shell also seems to handle transition animations a lot better so that's great.