# How can I display an image with View?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I want to display an image(Icon.png) on the entire screen when the user starts my application. The image(Icon.png) needs to be displayed until I execute layout.RemoveView(splashView); and the image(Icon.png) needs to be above the images that will get drawn later in void Draw(GameTime gameTime).

I get no error message, but my image(Icon.png) is never displayed on the screen and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

How can I display an image with View?

Activity1.cs:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Android.Widget;

namespace applogo
{
[Activity(
    Label = "@string/app_name",
    MainLauncher = true,
    Icon = "@drawable/icon",
    AlwaysRetainTaskState = true,
    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance,
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.FullUser,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.Keyboard | ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize
)]
public class Activity1 : AndroidGameActivity
{
    private Game1 _game;
    private View _view;
    FrameLayout layout;
    View splashView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        var g = new Game1();
        g.OnLoadingContent += G_OnLoadingContent;

        layout = new FrameLayout(this.ApplicationContext);
        layout.AddView((View)g.Services.GetService(typeof(View)));
        int id = Resources.GetIdentifier("Icon", "drawable", PackageName);
        splashView = new ImageView(this.ApplicationContext);
        splashView.SetBackgroundResource(id);
        layout.AddView(splashView);

        SetContentView(layout);
        g.Run();
    }

    private void G_OnLoadingContent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        layout.RemoveView(splashView);
    }
}
}
```

Game1.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;

namespace applogo
{
public class Game1 : Game
{
    private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
    private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;
    public event EventHandler OnLoadingContent;

    public Game1()
    {
        _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here

        OnLoadingContent?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

My Android project:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTicA.png)

**UPDATE:**

It works now. I changed my code in OnCreate(Bundle bundle) and I use now an .xml file(splash_screen_svg) instead of the .png file(Icon.png).

But at the beginning when my application starts there is only a white screen and the application's name before the splashView code is executed.

Would it be possible to display splashView immediately instead of the white screen and the application's name? Is it already possible to do this in AndroidManifest.xml or how could I do that?

Activity1.cs:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Android.Widget;

namespace applogo
{
[Activity(
    Label = "@string/app_name",
    MainLauncher = true,
    Icon = "@drawable/icon",
    AlwaysRetainTaskState = true,
    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance,
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.FullUser,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.Keyboard | ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize
)]
public class Activity1 : AndroidGameActivity
{
    private Game1 _game;
    private View _view;
    FrameLayout layout;
    View splashView;

 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
 {
     base.OnCreate(bundle);
     var g = new Game1();
     g.OnLoadingContent += G_OnLoadingContent;

     layout = new FrameLayout(this.ApplicationContext);
     layout.AddView((View)g.Services.GetService(typeof(View)));
     splashView = new ImageView(this.ApplicationContext);  

     ((ImageView)splashView).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.splash_screen_svg);
     layout.AddView(splashView);
     SetContentView(layout);
     g.Run();
 }

 private void G_OnLoadingContent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
     layout.RemoveView(splashView);
 }
}
}
```

splash_screen_svg.xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="320dp"
android:height="480dp"
android:viewportWidth="84.666664"
android:viewportHeight="127">
<path
  android:pathData="M0.529,0.529h83.608v125.942h-83.608z"
  android:strokeWidth="1.05833"
  android:fillColor="#00ffff"
  android:strokeColor="#000000"/>
<path
  android:pathData="M21.431,32.015h41.804v62.971h-41.804z"
  android:strokeWidth="0.529167"
  android:fillColor="#ff0000"
  android:strokeColor="#000000"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: If you want to show a image in the splashView, you can convert the view to the ImageView and set the image such as ((ImageView)splashView).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I have updated my code and questions. At the beginning when my application starts there is only a white screen and the application's name before the splashView code is executed.

Would it be possible to display splashView immediately instead of the white screen and the application's name? Is it already possible to do this in AndroidManifest.xml or how could I do that?

Comment: If you want the application show the image immediately when it starts, you can use a spalsh screen which extend the Activity and just do noting but show a image. You can follow the documents to do it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen

Comment: It works now. I created a splash screen theme and I use it when the user starts my game. After that, I create the splashView in OnCreate and I remove the splashView later in Game1.cs. And I use the same xml file to create the splash screen theme and the splashView. In this case, I don't get the white screen at the beginning.